# How can I recover ethereum account

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, password, recovery

I have created geth account. I know the password and trying to access my wallet through below command:

```
geth account update *ethereum_address*
```

I entered correct password but still I am getting below error:

> Fatal: Failed to unlock account *ethereum_address* (no key for given address or file)

I don't have private key. How can I use this wallet now?

Comment: your question is ambiguous. provide more details is it your coinbase account? are you on mainnet or testnet did you migrate your wallet or what exactly?

Comment: I started mining from this guide: https://github.com/angelomilan/ethereum-guides/blob/master/GPU-cloud_mining.md but, I can't access the account as I changed my VM. I don't have private key or wallet.json file

Comment: if you don't have the private key so you ve lost your account. try to retrive your keystor folder from your previous VM

Comment: @BadrBellaj : Unfortunately, VM is gone. :( (This is the ethereum account: `2bef01aa682e498d5c9d28da4ff28c9eee6f1608`)

Comment: The private key *is* your account. The password is just used to decrypt it. If you lost the private key, the account is gone, sorry...

Comment: I'm trying to relocate my account.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the account now.

The private key is your account and your password is used to decrypt it.

No private key = no account

An address & password without a private key to use against has no use.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get ahold of the private key then you're all set. Hopefully you can find it somewhere written down. B/c the password is your decryption key and the private key is your actual account.